# Which thread is used in the same function of multithread

Tags: multithreading, mfc

In mfc code,

Declare as follow

```
CWinThread* _pThread[5];
DWORD _ThreadArg[5] = { HIGHEST_THREAD, // 0x00
                    ABOVE_AVE_THREAD, // 0x3F
                    NORMAL_THREAD, // 0x7F
                    BELOW_AVE_THREAD, // 0xBF
                    LOWEST_THREAD // 0xFF
                    }; 

int i;
for (i= 0; i< 5; i++)
{
    _pThread[i] = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc,
                                &_ThreadArg[i],
                                THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
                                0,
                                //CREATE_SUSPENDED,
                                NULL,
                                NULL);
    //_pThread[i]->ResumeThread();
}
// setup relative priority of threads
_pThread[0]->SetThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
_pThread[1]->SetThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);
_pThread[2]->SetThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL);
_pThread[3]->SetThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL);
_pThread[4]->SetThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST);
```

use same thread function

```
UINT CThreadPoolDlg::ThreadFuncTh1(LPVOID ThreadArg)
{
    DWORD dwArg = *(DWORD*)ThreadArg;
    //txtTh[0].SetWindowTextW(_T("23"));
    AfxGetMainWnd()->GetDlgItem(IDC_THD1)->SetWindowText(_T("1"));
    return 0;
}
```

How do I check which thread is in use in same function?

Comment: Er, each thread has its own local `dwArg`, that clearly identifies the thread. What is the *real* issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: Besides, updating windows from a thread other than the owning thread is a sure recipe for disaster. Are you sure you want to be using MFC, when you are failing to understand even the basics of Windows GUI programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a answer as follow

```
_pThread[0] = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc,this,
                            THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
                            0,
                            NULL,
                            NULL);

_pThread[1] = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc,this,
                            THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
                            0,
                            CREATE_SUSPENDED,
                            NULL);

_pThread[2] = AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc,this,
                            THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,
                            0,
                            CREATE_SUSPENDED,
                            NULL);
```

the thread function is declare as follow

```
UINT CThreadPoolDlg::ThreadFunc(LPVOID ThreadArg)
{
    CThreadPoolDlg* dwArg = (CThreadPoolDlg*)ThreadArg;
    DWORD dThread = GetCurrentThreadId();

    //txtTh[0].SetWindowTextW(_T("23"));
    while(1)
    {   
        CString strTemp;

        if(dThread == dwArg->_pThread[0]->m_nThreadID)
        {           
            AfxGetMainWnd()->GetDlgItem(IDC_THD1)->GetWindowText(strTemp);      
            int n = _wtoi(strTemp);
            strTemp.Format(_T("%d"), ++n);      
            AfxGetMainWnd()->GetDlgItem(IDC_THD1)->SetWindowText(strTemp);

            if(n > 5)
            {
                ::SendMessage(dwArg->GetSafeHwnd(), OWM_MYMETHOD, 0, 0);
                //dwArg->_pThread[1]->ResumeThread();
            }
        }

        if(dThread == dwArg->_pThread[1]->m_nThreadID)
        {           
            AfxGetMainWnd()->GetDlgItem(IDC_THD2)->GetWindowText(strTemp);      
            int n = _wtoi(strTemp);
            strTemp.Format(_T("%d"), ++n);      
            AfxGetMainWnd()->GetDlgItem(IDC_THD2)->SetWindowText(strTemp);

            if(n > 5)
            {
                dwArg->_pThread[2]->ResumeThread();
            }
        }

        if(dThread == dwArg->_pThread[2]->m_nThreadID)
        {
            AfxGetMainWnd()->GetDlgItem(IDC_THD3)->GetWindowText(strTemp);
            int n = _wtoi(strTemp);
            strTemp.Format(_T("%d"), ++n);
            AfxGetMainWnd()->GetDlgItem(IDC_THD3)->SetWindowText(strTemp);
        }

        Sleep(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just look at the

```
DWORD dThread = GetCurrentThreadId();
dThread == dwArg->_pThread[1]->m_nThreadID
```

then I will get current thread id...